# How to create a carousel with a loop Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, json, frameworks, botframework, bots

Trying to create a carousel using **JSON** returned from an API. I'm trying to return one carousel with multiple images and you can scroll across to look at all images. I'm pretty sure it's something small I'm missing, any help is much appreciated.

```
                    RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(apiResponse);

                    var card = new HeroCard { };

                    List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
                    var reply = context.Activity.CreateReply();
                    Attachment plAttachment;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + result.results[i].poster_path));                           
                    }

                    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                    {
                        HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
                        {
                            Text = "Test",
                            Title = "Movies",
                            Images = cardImages,

                        };
                        plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                        reply.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
                    }
                    reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                    await context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }       
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

At the moment its returning multiple carousels with the same image:
[image: Bot Reply]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: your each HeroCard has 5 images, but i thing you should have one image in each HeroCard? can you please check that?

Comment: update this line and see, this might work for you? `Images = new CardImage(url: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + result.results[x].poster_path),`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @HasanMahmood, it appeared to be the way I was creating the HeroCard. I will update the post with the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already came up with this solution. It was edited out of your question, presumably because it should be posted as an answer. So here it is (slightly modified for efficiency) in case you want to mark this question as answered:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.results.Count(); i++)
{
    var data = result.results[i];
    var heroCard = new HeroCard
    {
        Title = data.title,
        Subtitle = "Rating: " + data.popularity,
        Text = data.overview,
        Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + data.poster_path) },
        Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Book", value: "https://www.odeoncinemas.ie/cinema-tickets") },
    };
    // Add the attachment to our reply.
    reply.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
}
reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
await context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```